# Convergence radius of a power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{2k}$ with $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{r}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

I need help for the following task:
Let {$a_n$}$_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{r}$ with $r$ being a positive real number.

Show that the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^{2k}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ has radius of convergence $\sqrt{r}$.

[image]

I mean this is the formula we have to work with. If we have $x^n$, then $a_n=1$ and the radius is $1$. But in this situation I don't get the result that I should have and I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: The $a_n$ is the coefficient of $x^{2n}$. The coefficients of the $x^{2n+1}$s are all zero. Thus the radius of convergence is $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{{\sqrt[{2n}]{{|a_n| }}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{{\sqrt {\sqrt[n]{{|a_n| }}} }} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {1/r} }}=\sqrt r.
$$

Comment: "If we have $x^n$, then $a_n=1$" Why? Why would $a_n$ be equal to $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us apply the root test to the proposed power series:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n}x^{2n}|^{1/n} = x^{2}\times\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n}|^{1/n} = \frac{x^{2}}{r} <  1 \Rightarrow |x| < \sqrt{r}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !